# View columns with NAs in R

Tags: r, row, na

Hei,
after I've already got so many helpful advices here, I'd like to ask a question concerning detecting NAs - is there any possibility to view the ROWS of a dataframe which include NAs?
The problem is that my dataframe's really huge so

> is.na(data_frame)

doesn't show me all the rows (not even nearly), so I only know how many NAs there are and in which columns they are but I would really like to know, whether they are in the same rows - which mean that they possibly cause each other. 
As an example for my data, I'll just give you the head of the dataframe, if you need more then tell me

```
  transect_id year day month      LST precipitation Quarter
1       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
2       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
3       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
4       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
5       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
6       TR001 2010 191     7 30.62083             0       3
    SumPre average.temp  MinTemp  MaxTemp prev.temp prev.Precip
1 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
2 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
3 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
4 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
5 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
6 1.895143     30.78058 27.73995 33.54386  30.43515           0
                     species regional_gam prop_pheno_sampled
1           Pontia daplidice      0.00000          0.4496937
2 Polyommatus icarus zelleri      0.00000          0.3952952
3       Gonepteryx cleopatra      1.30963          0.4731522
4           Anaphaeis aurota      0.00000          0.3731392
5         Carcharodus alceae      0.00000          0.1646973
6            Euchloe belemia      1.40654          0.3373209
```

If I could see the rows with the NAs I could e.g. check, whether there are NAs for the LST (landscape surface temperature) in the same lines as NAs in the MaxTemp - so it would be obvious that one causes the other.

I hope I got my question clear :-)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df[,sapply(df,function(x)any(is.na(x)))]` for columns, `df[apply(df,1,function(x)any(is.na(x)))]` for rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always use is

```
df[rowSums(is.na(df))>0,]
```

This gives you all rows with at least one `NA`. It should be also fairly efficient since `rowSums` is a really fast `base` function.

Or for columns

```
df[,colSums(is.na(df))>0]
```

Comment: Thanks, that just worked out fine :-) Sometimes it's more simple than I think.